# Generate prediction sequence with transformers model built from scratch

Tags: pytorch, nlp, encoder-decoder

I'm building a basic transformers models from scratch in PyTorch (with simple tokenization and no masking).  I'm using 'The Mysterious Island' by Jules Verne as the training set, so download it from [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1268/pg1268.txt) and place in the appropriate directory locally to run the code below.

I'm having trouble conceptualizing and coding how I would predict on new text.  It's possible that my encoder/decoder_input shapes are incorrect.  The way I have it set up is that the input_encoder is a sequence of 30 tokens (tokens 1-30 in the corpus for the first example), and the input_decoder is tokens 2-31 in the corpus for the first example.

My output has the same shape as the input (i.e. 1, context_size, vocab_size).  When I predict, I feed in the start sequence padded with enough tokens to get to the context size as the input_encoder.  The input_decoder is a start-of-sequence token with padded tokens up to the context size.

When I call the forward method during prediction, I'm under the impression that the model should be autoregressive.  By that logic, I should just get 1 new token that I would add to the input_decoder with each pass-through.  However, the output from one forward pass has n tokens (n = context size).

Perhaps that latter part of my setup is incorrect?  If the output is predicted 30 words at once, then maybe I don't need to use the autoregressive approach?

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

import torch.optim as optim

from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, context_size, d_model):
        super().__init__()

        self.encoding = torch.zeros(context_size, d_model)

        pos = torch.arange(0, context_size).unsqueeze(dim=1)
        dim = torch.arange(
            0, d_model, 2)  # dim is i in the positional encoding formula
        self.encoding[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(pos / (10000**(2 * dim / d_model)))
        self.encoding[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(pos / (10000**(2 * dim / d_model)))

    def forward(self, x):
        seq_len = x.size(1)
        return self.encoding[:seq_len, :]

class PositionwiseFeedForward(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, d_model, d_ff):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        return x

class EncoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, d_ff):
        super().__init__()
        self.self_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.feed_forward = PositionwiseFeedForward(d_model, d_ff)
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)

    def forward(self, x):
        hidden_states, _ = self.self_attn(query=x, key=x, value=x)
        x = self.norm1(x + hidden_states)
        ff_output = self.feed_forward(x)
        x = self.norm2(x + ff_output)
        return x

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    # input_size - # rows in token embedding
    # context size - # rows in positional embedding
    # d_ff - internal dimension of the FF network
    # num encoder blocks
    def __init__(self, input_size, context_size, d_model, d_ff, num_heads,
                 n_blocks):
        super().__init__()

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, d_model)
        self.pos_embedding = PositionalEncoding(context_size, d_model)

        self.blocks = nn.ModuleList([
            EncoderBlock(
                d_model=d_model,
                num_heads=num_heads,
                d_ff=d_ff,
            ) for _ in range(n_blocks)
        ])

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x) + self.pos_embedding(x)
        for block in self.blocks:
            x = block(x)
        return x

class DecoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, d_ff):
        super().__init__()
        self.self_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.cross_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.feed_forward = PositionwiseFeedForward(d_model, d_ff)
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.norm3 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)

    def forward(self, x, enc_output):
        hidden_states, _ = self.self_attn(x, x, x)
        x = self.norm1(x + hidden_states)
        hidden_states, _ = self.cross_attn(
                             query=x, key=enc_output, value=enc_output)
        x = self.norm2(x + hidden_states)
        ff_output = self.feed_forward(x)
        x = self.norm3(x + ff_output)
        return x

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output_size, context_size,
                 d_model, d_ff, num_heads, n_blocks):
        super().__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(output_size, d_model)
        self.pos_embedding = PositionalEncoding(context_size, d_model)

        self.blocks = nn.ModuleList([
            DecoderBlock(
                d_model=d_model,
                num_heads=num_heads,
                d_ff=d_ff,
            )
            for _ in range(n_blocks)
        ])

        self.out = nn.Linear(d_model, output_size)

    def forward(self, x, enc_output):
        x = self.embedding(x) + self.pos_embedding(x)

        for block in self.blocks:
            x = block(x, enc_output)

        output = self.out(x)
        return output

class Transformer(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vocab_size, context_size,
                 d_model, d_ff, num_heads, n_blocks):
        super().__init__()

        self.encoder = Encoder(
            vocab_size,
            context_size,
            d_model,
            d_ff,
            num_heads,
            n_blocks
        )

        self.decoder = Decoder(
            vocab_size,
            context_size,
            d_model,
            d_ff,
            num_heads,
            n_blocks
        )

    def forward(self, input_encoder, input_decoder):
        enc_output = self.encoder(input_encoder)   # (64, 100, 10)
        output = self.decoder(input_decoder, enc_output)  # input_decoder shape - (64, 99)
        return output

## Prep data
with open('your_directory/1268-0.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as fp:
    text=fp.read()

start_indx = text.find('THE MYSTERIOUS ISLAND')
end_indx = text.find('End of the Project Gutenberg')

text = text[start_indx:end_indx]

SOS_token = 0
EOS_token = 1
PAD_token = 2   # Need to have padding so that the input & output sentences
# are the same length - required for the cross-attention computation

index2words = {SOS_token: 'SOS', EOS_token: 'EOS', PAD_token: 'PAD'}

words_list = set(text.split(' '))

for word in words_list:
    index2words[len(index2words)] = word

words2index = {w: i for i, w in index2words.items()}

text_encoded = np.array(
    [words2index[word] for word in text.split(' ')],
    dtype=np.int32)

CONTEXT_SIZE = 30
chunk_size = CONTEXT_SIZE  + 1

# n chunks where each next chunk is 1 word offset from the previous chunk
token_chunks = [
    text_encoded[i:i + chunk_size]
    for i in range(len(text_encoded) - chunk_size + 1)
]

class TextDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, text_chunks):
        self.text_chunks = text_chunks

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.text_chunks)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text_chunk = self.text_chunks[idx]
        return text_chunk[:-1].long(), text_chunk[1:].long()

seq_dataset = TextDataset(torch.tensor(token_chunks))

BATCH_SIZE = 50
seq_dl = DataLoader(seq_dataset,
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    shuffle=True,
                    drop_last=True)

## Build model
EPOCHS = 10
VOCAB_SIZE = len(words2index)
D_MODEL = 10
D_FF = 20
NUM_HEADS = 2
N_BLOCKS = 12

model = Transformer(
    vocab_size=VOCAB_SIZE,
    context_size=CONTEXT_SIZE,
    d_model=D_MODEL,
    d_ff=D_FF,  # internal dimension of the feed forward network
    num_heads=NUM_HEADS,
    n_blocks=N_BLOCKS)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=0)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9)

model.train()

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for src_data, tgt_data in seq_dl:
        output = model(src_data, tgt_data)
        loss = criterion(
            output.view(-1, VOCAB_SIZE),
            tgt_data.view(-1))  # CrossEntropyLoss requires preds to be
        # shape (batch_size, num_classes) and actual to be shape (batch_size), so need to reshape
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}, Loss: {loss.item()}")

## Predict sequence
prediction_start = "And then they set sail again for another land"

with torch.no_grad():
    # Assuming you have a method to tokenize the input words and convert them into input_tokens
    encoder_tokens = convert2tensors(prediction_start, CONTEXT_SIZE)

    # Initialize input_decoder with a start token
    input_decoder = SOS_token
    decoder_tokens = torch.tensor([input_decoder] + [PAD_token] * (CONTEXT_SIZE-1))

    # Generate predictions iteratively until an end token is generated or a maximum length is reached
    while len(decoder_tokens) < CONTEXT_SIZE:
        # Call the forward method of your Transformer class to generate predictions
        output = model(encoder_tokens, decoder_tokens)

        # Append the predicted token to the input_decoder
        decoder_tokens.append(output)

        # Break the loop if the end token is generated
        if EOS_token in output:
            break
```